# On which servers can i deploy Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Im a beginner in Ruby on Rails and i asked me on which servers i can deploy the framework! 
I heard a lot about Heroku, but they was asking me if i can start a ruby on rails application with a database of 4000-10000 entries (i mean little traffic!) on a local server for example from  the german company protonet here is the link:
 http://protonet.info

Or on an simple windows,linux server? With an Xeon Processor?

Or can somebody suggest a solution for a local server without binding to the internet? the website itself only needs to be visible in the local network!

I thank you a lot!

Comment: This would be a better question for Google as it doesn't really fit the format of Stack Overflow. Check out the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more information.

Comment: I tried it but didnt get answers! Sorry i knew that it is a little bit controversial!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can deploy locally. First thing you'll want to try is 'rails s -p 3000'. Bingo. You now have a fully functional rails server working on your local network. Try accessing it with your ip address and the port. You can deploy on both Windows and Linux, but based on my own experience, you'll prefer Linux (faster and easier).

Windows, with Thin server as a service : http://www.dixis.com/?p=140

Linux : [Ideal Rails Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485074/ideal-rails-server)

Comment: Is it slowly on (normal local servers) or wich requierments are needed?

Comment: Ruby is slower, way slower. But it will work. And with a low level of traffic, it should even work quite well.

Answer (score 1):

In general any Unix(y) or Windows server (not recommended) should do it. Most shared hosting companies don't suport ruby so a VPS might be in order for public internet. I deploy always on Ubuntu and just moved to digitalocean.com ($5 / month for a basic VPS) - not endorsing as just moved last week. For internal, I'd suggest a Unix server and possibly rvm for having dedicated ruby install for app.

Heroku / Engine Yard also options.